# Spring boot 1.5.x compatibility with Java 11

Tags: java, spring-boot, compatibility, java-11

Can Spring boot version 1.5.x be used with Java 11?
Or is it necessary to move it to Spring 2.1.x?

Comment: You need to migrate to 2.1 check this migration guide:https://dzone.com/articles/migrating-springboot-applications-to-latest-java-v

Answer (score 3):

Spring Boot 1.5 can be used with the version 8 of java. In order to use Java9 you need SpringBoot 2.0. In order to use Java11 you need SpringBoot 2.1.X, as you mentioned.

Here is some case study on a migration you might be interested in: https://altkomsoftware.pl/en/blog/spring-boot-migration-java/

Comment: Yes but if I still want to use 1.5.x with Java 11, would there be a problem?

Comment: Yes, read my comment carefully, for java11 spring boot version needs to be >= 2.1.0